# Combinatorics Notation : $S(j,k)$

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I've encountered with following identity :

$\binom{i+j}{j}S(n, i+j) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}S(k,i)S(n-k,j)$

What does $S( i,j)$ refer to?

Comment: Stirling numbers of the first kind ... $6^{th}$ equation in the section on finite sums https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Finite_sums

Comment: Thx. Just checked it. Do you think it's worth to remain this post or better to delete?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit The notation $S(j,k)$, with capital S, is often used for Stirling numbers of the second kind.  The usual notation for Stirling numbers of the first kind uses lower-case s: $s(i,j)$